# How to select a multiple items in a web form filling from a spread sheet using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

> Hello, As mentioned in the spread sheet column "F" there are multiple years separated with comma.I want to select those Years in a web page using VBA.If it is single year it is selecting correctly.But not if multiple years. Normally in manual method I will press and hold CTRL key in Keyboard and select.
>   If someone could help me with a idea to fix it .I will feel awesome.

```
Sub copy_project_loop()
```

Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim SHELL_OBJECT
SHELL_OBJECT = "WScript.Shell"
Set objShell = CreateObject(SHELL_OBJECT)

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "URL"

```
Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set Doc = IE.document
```

For intRow = 2 To 2

```
Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Doc.getElementById("lstQualifierTypes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("F1").Value
Doc.getElementById("Search").Click
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Doc.getElementById("lstQualifiers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("F" & intRow).Value
Doc.getElementById("ADD").Click

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

Next

End Sub

```html
<table>
<tbody><tr><td colspan="2">
Time Study Nbr:<img src="../images/closeup.gif" height="11" width="11">
<input type="text" name="txtTimeStudyNbr" size="15" maxlength="10" value="4750843">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

</td>
<td rowspan="2">

<select name="lstQualifiers" style="FONT-FAMILY:monospace;" multiple="" size="5">

<option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option></select>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Qualifier Type: 

<select name="lstQualifierTypes" style="FONT-FAMILY:monospace;" onchange="return lstQualifierTypes_onchange(this)">
<option></option>
```

[image][image]

Comment: Is there a public url to test with?

Comment: No  it is password protected